# scikit learn logistic regression model tfidfvectorizer

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, tfidfvectorizer

I am trying to create a logistic regression model using scikit learn with the code below. I am using 9 columns for the features (X) and one for the label (Y). When trying to fit I get an error "ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [9, 560000]" even though previously the lengths of X and Y are the same, if I use x.transpose() i get a different error "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'". I am assuming this has to do with the tfidfvectorizer possibly, I am doing this because 3 of the columns contain single words and wasn't working. Is this the right way to be doing this or should I be converting the words in the columns separately and then using train_test_split? If not why am I getting the errors and how can I fic them. Heres an example of the [csv](https://gist.github.com/ishikawa-rei/54f315889b3b66d7f2678b213db80a21).

```
df = pd.read_csv("UNSW-NB15_1.csv",header=None, names=cols, encoding = "UTF-8",low_memory=False) 

df.to_csv('netraf.csv')
csv = 'netraf.csv'
my_df = pd.read_csv(csv)

x_features = my_df.columns[1:10]
x_data = my_df[x_features]
Y = my_df["Label"]

x_train, x_validation, y_train, y_validation = 
model_selection.train_test_split(x_data, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=7)

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
lr = LogisticRegression()
tfidf_lr_pipe = Pipeline([('tfidf', tfidf_vectorizer), ('lr', lr)])

tfidf_lr_pipe.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Can you add to your question a minimal example of your csv file that reproduces the error. It will help users answer your question.

Comment: There are many issues here. First of all, the error you get is because `TfidfVectorizer`expects to get only **one** column, not a multicolumn dataframe.  Why do you need to use `TfidfVectorizer` on all the dataframe anyway? Also, the data contains `NaN` values, even in `Label` column, which is **very** weird.

Comment: Im not sure how to use TfidfVectorizer thats why I was using it on whole dataframe. Whats the better way to do it ? use it on the required columns individually and then pass that to train_test_split ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is unusual because `TfidfVectorizer` is designed to extract numerical features from text. But if you don't really care and just want to make your code works, one way to do it is by converting your numerical data to string and configure `TfidfVectorizer` to accept tokenized data:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

cols = ['srcip','sport','dstip','dsport','proto','service','smeansz','dmeansz','attack_cat','Label']
df = pd.read_csv("UNSW-NB15_1.csv",header=None, names=cols, encoding = "UTF-8",low_memory=False) 

df.to_csv('netraf.csv')
csv = 'netraf.csv'
my_df = pd.read_csv(csv)

# convert all columns to string like we don't care
for col in my_df.columns:
    my_df[col] = my_df[col].astype(str)

# replace nan with empty string like we don't care
for col in my_df.columns[my_df.isna().any()].tolist():
    my_df.loc[:, col].fillna('', inplace=True)

x_features = my_df.columns[1:10]
x_data = my_df[x_features]
Y = my_df["Label"]

x_train, x_validation, y_train, y_validation = model_selection.train_test_split(
    x_data.values, Y.values, test_size=0.2, random_state=7)

# configure TfidfVectorizer to accept tokenized data
# reference http://www.davidsbatista.net/blog/2018/02/28/TfidfVectorizer/
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(
    analyzer='word',
    tokenizer=lambda x: x,
    preprocessor=lambda x: x,
    token_pattern=None)

lr = LogisticRegression()
tfidf_lr_pipe = Pipeline([('tfidf', tfidf_vectorizer), ('lr', lr)])
tfidf_lr_pipe.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

That being said, I'd recommend you to use another method to do feature engineering on your dataset. For example, you can try [to encode your nominal data](http://pbpython.com/categorical-encoding.html) (eg. IP, port) to numerical value.